# I want to convert date "2018-05-18 17:16:24.570" to "7/26/2018, 10:42 AM" format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am retrieving the date as a `string` from the database and then need to convert it. So that prints in a *different format*.
I am using

```
string date = dr[2].ToString();

date = DateTime
  .ParseExact(date,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt ",new CultureInfo.InvariantCulture("enUS"));
```

But this does not work:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

Comment: Dates have no formats. They are *binary* values. There's nothing to convert. Everything works as it should. When you try to *display* the date to the end user, use the appropriate format string or CultureInfo on the view, form, textbox or whatever you use to display it

Comment: Formats matter when converting *between* strings and datetimes. When it's stored in a datetime, it doesn't *have* a format. Avoid needlessly converting properly typed data into strings just to present yourself with problems converting the data back to the correct data type.

Comment: What's `dr[2]`?

Comment: You can use `date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: What you posted won't compile anyway. You can't assing a DateTime to a string variable. If `dr[2]` returns a DateTime just *cast* it to a DateTime and store it into a DateTime variable, eg `var date= (DateTime)dr[2];` You don't need to do anything more

Comment: Yeah you are right, just now I realize that the date he wants to convert and the expected results are complete different.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos : What you said doen't make sense. date.ToString() does not change the date, only outputs a string.

Answer (score 4):

If you work with `string` you can put `ParseExact` followed by `ToString`:

```
  string date = "2018-05-18 17:16:24.570";

  // 5/18/2018 05:16 PM
  date = DateTime
    .ParseExact(date, "yyyy-M-d H:m:s.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm ttt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

However, it seems you are working with `DataReader` (`dr[2]` fragment); if it's your case, `Convert` is a better option than `ParseExact` (providing that RDBMS has corresponding `Date` field):

```
  string date = Convert
    .ToDateTime(dr[2])
    .ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm ttt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

**Edit:** If you want to change time from UTC to a TimeZone you can try `TimeZoneInfo` (see all available Time Zones [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg154758(v=winembedded.80))) e.g.

```
  //TODO: Put the right Time Zone Id here 
  // Or should it be "Arabian Standard Time"? I've tried to guess 
  TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time");

  string date = TimeZoneInfo
    .ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert
       .ToDateTime(dr[2]), zone)
    .ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm ttt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: when i use this i am getting error :-System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' 
I am trying to fetch the date stored in the table and then compare it to the one that gets displayed on th webpage.Using selenium.

Comment: @Mahak Malik: please, provide the string *sample* which is in wrong format.

Comment: dr[2] is the row that gets fetched using query.

Comment: I see: `dr[2]` is 2nd column from the `DataReader dr`. Does it field contains `DateTime`, not `String`?

Comment: Thank you, I see; `@"select FirstName,LastName,QueryDate from ...` Is `QueryDate` of type `Date` (or `DateTime` or alike)?

Comment: yup it's of type datetime [CreationDateUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL.

Comment: i am trying to upload screenshot but dont know how

Comment: Do you use the code with `Convert.ToDateTime(...)`? `'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'` means that `string` appears somewhere

Comment: The second piece of code that you posted works fine.
Thankyou

Comment: One more issue. The date in Db is in utc i.e 19 Pm corresponds to 3PM on the page.When actually it should have been 7 Pm. How to convert it into 3pm time zone? it is  4 hour difference @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @Mahak Malik: If you want to switch from UTC to a TimeZone, try `DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeInUtc, zone);`. Please, see my edit.